# php ajax works but not on localhost

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I recently inherited a project at work and I'm trying to set up a local instance on my localhost so I can work with it and not affect the live site. The problem is that some of the ajax calls are giving me errors on response. id is a user id and in the working instance this returns any row in the permissions table that has an id matching the one in the users table. This is only an issue on localhost. Any advice on why this is happening appreciated. Thanks.

### Ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../wwwroot/models/apm/CheckAdmin.php',
    data: {
        eid: id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        if (data[0].status == 2) {
            ret = true;
            $('#devTimeGrp').show();

            $('#mngTab').show();
            console.log("anAdmin............");
        }
        else {
            ret = false;
            $('#devTimeGrp').show();
            $('#mngTab').hide();
            console.log("notAdmin......");
            //$('#mngTab').show();
        }
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
});
```

### PHP

```
<?php
include("../db-settings.php");

$eid = $_POST['eid'];

echo $eid;

$sql="call CheckAdmin('$eid')";

$result = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3);

while($result->fetch()){
    $out[] = array( 'id' => $col1,
                    'user' => $col2,
                    'status' => $col3);
}
echo json_encode($out);
$result->close();
?>
```

### Stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myDB`@`%` PROCEDURE `CheckAdmin`(IN p_eid CHAR(36))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM user_permission WHERE (SELECT id FROM users WHERE uid = p_eid) = user_id;
END
```

### Error

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement
```

Comment: how many columns does user_permission have?

Comment: This error is telling you that when you call the `bind_result` function, you're trying to bind more variables than what actually is returned

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Or less variables. BTW, you should use `bind_param` when making the query, instead of doing variable substitution in the SQL.

Comment: is `url: '../wwwroot/models/apm/CheckAdmin.php'` exposed to a public? I would suggest doing AJAX with absolute path to avoid confusion with relative paths. e.g. `url: '/modes/this/that.php`

Comment: There are only three columns in user_permission and I have made sure the path is correct, I got the same result with the absolute path.

Comment: I was using the wrong username lol. Thanks for the advice tho.

Answer (score 1):

Change the procedure so that it only returns the 3 columns you're binding. Also, I recommend using a `JOIN` instead of the subquery, as MySQL is notoriously poor at optimizing that syntax.

```
SELECT p.id, p.user, p.status
FROM user_permissions AS p
JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE u.uid = p_eid\
```

If you can't change the procedure, you need to change the PHP so that it binds as many variables as the number of columns in the `user_permissions` table.

And to avoid SQL injection problems, use `bind_param` when making the query:

```
$sql = "CALL CheckAdmin(?)";
$result = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$result->bind_param("s", $eid);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already thought of this. Those are the only three columns in the table. Thats why it seems odd to me. It should be returning a matching number of columns and on the web server it works.

Comment: My guess is your table schema is different on localhost than it is on the server.

Comment: Thanks, yes I just figured it out and thats pretty close. I was using the wrong username in my stored procedure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try `SELECT id,user,status FROM user_permission` instead of `SELECT *`
2. If the first not working

   `var_dump($col1);
      var_dump($col2);
      var_dump($col3);`
   Maybe a variable is array.

Comment: Thanks, Had already tried this. It turned out to be a wrong username.